# Tooltip backgroundColor depending on chart color ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I would set the background colour of tooltips depending on graph

Here's how I made

```
tooltips: {
        yPadding: -2,
        xPadding: 10,
        footerMarginTop: 5,
        titleFontColor: '#FFF',
        displayColors: false,
        backgroundColor: function(tooltipItem: Chart.ChartTooltipItem, chart: Chart) {
            const bgColor = `${chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].pointBorderColor.toString()}`;
            return bgColor;
        }
```

But I get the error

> Property 'setTransform' is missing in type '(tooltipItem: ChartTooltipItem, chart: Chart) => string' but required in type 'CanvasPattern'. [2322]

I have also to do it in  `callbacks`

```
callbacks: {
    labelColor: function(tooltipItem: Chart.ChartTooltipItem, chart: Chart) {
        const bgColor = `${chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].pointBorderColor.toString()}`;
        return {
            backgroundColor: bgColor,
            borderColor: ''
        };
    },
}
```

but the colour is not getting applicated, I get black colour instead of `pointBorderColor` colour which is not black. ( I get well a colour code )

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign Anonymous method to the **backgroundColor** property. write conditions inside a method and return color hashcode as string and just call that method from backgroundColor property .

For example , the method name is x which is returning the color code. then the code will be `backgroundColor: x()`

Comment: I made like to say    `backgroundColor: this.getTooltipBgcolor(value)` I get error `Cannot find name 'value'.` . I wrote backgoundColor right after tooltip item, not inside callbacks